# Python: Group a list of file names according to common name identifier

Tags: python, regex, parsing

In a directory I have some files:

```
temperature_Resu05_les_spec_r0.0300.0
temperature_Resu05_les_spec_r0.0350.0
temperature_Resu05_les_spec_r0.0400.0
temperature_Resu05_les_spec_r0.0450.0
temperature_Resu06_les_spec_r0.0300.0
temperature_Resu06_les_spec_r0.0350.0
temperature_Resu06_les_spec_r0.0400.0
temperature_Resu06_les_spec_r0.0450.0
temperature_Resu07_les_spec_r0.0300.0
temperature_Resu07_les_spec_r0.0350.0
temperature_Resu07_les_spec_r0.0400.0
temperature_Resu07_les_spec_r0.0450.0
temperature_Resu08_les_spec_r0.0300.0
temperature_Resu08_les_spec_r0.0350.0
temperature_Resu08_les_spec_r0.0400.0
temperature_Resu08_les_spec_r0.0450.0
temperature_Resu09_les_spec_r0.0300.0
temperature_Resu09_les_spec_r0.0350.0
temperature_Resu09_les_spec_r0.0400.0
temperature_Resu09_les_spec_r0.0450.0
```

I need a list of all the files that have the same identifier XXXX as in `_rXXXX`. For example one such list would be composed of

```
temperature_Resu05_les_spec_r0.0300.0
temperature_Resu06_les_spec_r0.0300.0
temperature_Resu07_les_spec_r0.0300.0
temperature_Resu08_les_spec_r0.0300.0
temperature_Resu09_les_spec_r0.0300.0
```

I don't know a priori what the XXXX values are going to be so I can't iterate through them and match like that. Im thinking this might best be handles with a regular expression. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No a regex is not the best way, you pattern is very straight forward, just *str.rsplit* on the `_r` and use the right element of the split as the key to group the data with. A [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will do the grouping efficiently:

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open("yourfile") as f:
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        groups[line.rsplit("_r",1)[1]].append(line.rstrip())

from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(groups.values())
```

Which for your sample will give you:

```
[['temperature_Resu09_les_spec_r0.0450.0'],
 ['temperature_Resu05_les_spec_r0.0300.0',
  'temperature_Resu06_les_spec_r0.0300.0',
  'temperature_Resu07_les_spec_r0.0300.0',
  'temperature_Resu08_les_spec_r0.0300.0',
  'temperature_Resu09_les_spec_r0.0300.0'],
 ['temperature_Resu05_les_spec_r0.0400.0',
  'temperature_Resu06_les_spec_r0.0400.0',
  'temperature_Resu07_les_spec_r0.0400.0',
  'temperature_Resu08_les_spec_r0.0400.0',
  'temperature_Resu09_les_spec_r0.0400.0'],
 ['temperature_Resu05_les_spec_r0.0450.0',
  'temperature_Resu06_les_spec_r0.0450.0',
  'temperature_Resu07_les_spec_r0.0450.0',
  'temperature_Resu08_les_spec_r0.0450.0'],
 ['temperature_Resu05_les_spec_r0.0350.0',
  'temperature_Resu06_les_spec_r0.0350.0',
  'temperature_Resu07_les_spec_r0.0350.0',
  'temperature_Resu08_les_spec_r0.0350.0',
  'temperature_Resu09_les_spec_r0.0350.0']]
```

Comment: Thanks! Hmm so when is regex preferred? Im wondering if it is worth learning, as it seems there is always an easier method!

Comment: Out of curiosity where did you learn these methods!? I find them so useful but I never would have come across this defaultdict. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, regular expressions are a fun way to do it! It could look something like this:

```
results = {}
for fname in fnames:
    id = re.search('.*_r(.*)', fname).group(1) # grabs whatever is after the final "_r" as an identifier
    if id in results:
         results[id] += fname
    else:
         results[id] = [fname]
```

The results will be stored in a dictionary, `results`, indexed by the id.

I should add that this will work as long as all file names reliably have the _rXXXX structure. If there's any chance that a file name will not match that pattern, you will have to check for it and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this, I went with the 'simpler' approach in the end!